# Redirect to login page instead of index page in Yii

Tags: php, yii

When I am going to my application, the page is redirect to the index page in Yii.

As per requirement, I want to redirect to the login page of the user module just like `/user/login`.

So for doing that I have changed the `sitecontroller` code index to `user/login`, but it showed an error.

Can some one tell me how to redirect the `user/login` page by default instead of index page? Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check [this thread on Yii framework forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/24895-want-to-change-default-url-from-siteindex-to-mycontrollermyaction/).

Copy/paste of the answer (by *jodev*):

> No need to extend anything. All you have to do is open up
>   `protected/config/main.php` and add the following to the config array:
>
> ```
> return array(
>     'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..',
>     'name' => 'My application',
>     'defaultController' => 'myController/myAction', // <--- add this line and replace with correct controller/action
> ```

Comment: The code will be like this `return array(
  'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
  'name'=>'My Application',
  'defaultController'=> 'user/Login',`

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to a particular controller/action

```
$this->redirect(array('controller/action'));
```

Before getting to the View and its form, let’s be clear as to how the View accesses the specific Model. A Controller may have this code:

```
public function actionCreate() {

    $model=new Employee;

    /* Code for validation and redirect upon save. */

    // If not saved, render the create View:
    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model, // Model is passed to create.php View!
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to login page
$this->redirect(array('/site/login'));

Comment: yes this will redirect to the login page but if you are using user module and want o redirect to the user login page it will not work.